# How do I suppress spurious line breaks in a DataGrid?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid created like so:-

```
<asp:DataGrid id="myGrid"
              BorderWidth="1"
              CellPadding="3"
              AutoGenerateColumns="true"
              runat="server"
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="myGridSelectedCallback">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="subHeader"></HeaderStyle >
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonColumn HeaderText=""
                          ButtonType="LinkButton"
                          Text="Display"
                          CommandName="Select">
        </asp:ButtonColumn>
     </Columns>
 </asp:DataGrid>
```

And columns are added to it in the codebehind like this:-

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MyCol", typeof(string)));
```

but when I add lines to it, sometimes the text in the column wraps to another line. There doesn't appear to be any reason for this; the MaxLength for the column is -1, and there are no line break or other control characters in the added string.

What I'd like to happen is for the column to be widened to accommodate the longest string in it (the strings are only ~20 chars or so). I can't find anything on this as everyone else seems to have the opposite problem.

(This grid is contained within a `div`, but the `div` has no maximum width.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `HeaderStyle-Wrap="False"`

```
<asp:DataGrid id="DataGrid1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderStyle-Wrap="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Wrap="False"></asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Also, you can check this:[DataGrid Web Server control wraps when the ItemStyle Wrap property or the HeaderStyle Wrap property is set to false in Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323169)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Putting this in forced a horizontal scroll bar to appear, showing that the `div` was restricted in width and the cause of the wrapping, its width being limited by...er...who the fsck knows what. But that's another problem.